# Matlab imellipse: How to select active ellipse and delete it on image

Tags: image, matlab, user-interface, geometry, draggable

I am trying to write a GUI that will allow user to

1) create as many as draggable circles after pushing Add Circle button

I designed the function as below. It inserts fixed sized circles on the image each time I hit 'add' button. I count the push button hit number, too (in case I use it as a loop index)

```
function Add_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to Add (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)   

diameter = 30;   

    handles.trap = imellipse(gca,[100, 100, diameter, diameter]);
    addNewPositionCallback(handles.trap ,@(p) title(mat2str(p,3)));
    fcn = makeConstrainToRectFcn('imellipse',get(gca,'XLim'),get(gca,'YLim'));
    setFixedAspectRatioMode(handles.trap,'True');
    setPositionConstraintFcn(handles.trap,fcn);
    wait(handles.trap);

handles.count = handles.count+1
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

2) drag them to desired positions - It is automatically done by Matlab :)

3) select the active circle (e.g. set_as_Active function) - Here is the problem.

4) delete the one that the user think is unnecessary with a button (e.g. Delete_Circle) or with double click if possible

Since I can not select the active circle, when I hit delete, it deletes the updated handle object and next time it gives error.

```
delete(handles.trap);
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

I have used imellipse function to add draggable circles. However, I could not update the positions of the circles and select the desired circle as active. How can I do that?

Thanks for the helps.

Comment: A small, reproducible example would be good.

Comment: I have edited the question with my trial code, Arpi. Thanks.

Comment: Well, I solved it in a dirty way. Calculated distance of cursor position and objects and find the index of the minimum. I used ginput to obtain cursor position. By the way, I extended delete function to update selected objects in an array and find the unselected ones. The indexes of them were used in for loop in active object selection function.